# key - value mapping in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashtable

Whenever I wanted to use a general purpose data structure like a Set or Map in Java, I was presented with HashSet and HashMap. Upon searching more about these, I've read about the *hash table* that sits at the base of them. So I learned that, in order to map a key to its corresponding value, it uses a hash function.
My question is: why not use a simple by-index correspondence?
I tried to answer myself but I'm not sure of the correctness of the advantages:
by-index
+ faster, since there's no computation involved
+ collision-free
by-hash
+ memory economy, since a third array would be needed to correlate the keys and values

But I always thought that a few flops are more precious than a few bytes. Anyway, I don't think there is such a DS in Java as a simple IndexMap, is it? What am I missing here?

EDIT:
By *by-index* I mean this: an array is by construction an ordered structure, it has indices; so having 2 arrays to correlate, say, keys[] and values[] would mean keys[i] corresponds to values[i]. So, no relation function needed. I'm surely missing something here and I want to see what.

Comment: What is the index of the key "ThisIsMyKey"?  Also no "flops" are involved as there is no floating point here.  You _really_ need to review basic data structures.  Your question indicates you're missing some basic concepts.

Comment: What do you mean, "by-index"? Are you talking about Lists...?

Comment: Perhaps some links to what you are talking about. Perhaps your comparing hash tables to tree structures?

Comment: how are you going to find an element if you have lets say 1m elements in you array based or index based collection. Its going to be costly by-index but very fast by-hashcode

Comment: @Jim:  I don't understand what you mean by ThisIsMyKey. By flops I meant a measure of computing speed, that was a general principle.  2rs2ts: I edited my question, please, take a look.  Adam: In a HashMap I basically have 2 arrays (array as a concept) to relate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why not use a simple by-index correspondence?

Because this would break the `Set` contract for that particular implementation; in a `Set`, all values must be unique according to a defined criterion. In `HashSet`, this is the equality (as in `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`) of objects.

Also, a `Set` has no iteration order guarantee -- again, by contract. Therefore you cannot use indices to locate anything in a `Set`, even if you know its `.size()` (unlike in a `List`, which looks more like what you want, you will notice that a `Set` has no `.get()` method).

Note that keys in a `Map` are also a `Set`; keys in a `Map` are unique.

Another advantage of using a hash table is the speed of lookup operations (as in `.contains()`).

Comment: My guess at what the OP is asking is why are all Maps not like `EnumMap`s which use an array because of the symbolic and immutable nature of enums.

Comment: Well, there is `IdentityHash{Set,Map}` but their uses are peculiar

Comment: It's funny that `TreeSet` has a natural ordering, but you can't access elements at arbitrary indices without using an iterator and counting. Not that that really means much of anything.

Comment: @Adam, I'm still reading on the EnumMap and it's closed to what I was talking about, except for I want to put arbitrary objects instead of ones in an enum.

Comment: @user2320553 look at `IdentityHash{Set,Map}` then; but until you are guaranteed to use singletons, they will be of little use. It _is_ useful if your keys are `Class` objects since all `Class` objects are singletons.

Comment: fge, so keys in a map could have been an array but are a Set to keep the compatibility? I may be biased but Sets has the disadvantage that they're not indexed.

Comment: Read my answer again. This is not in the contract of `Set`s to be indexed and in fact you have no method to access a `Set` by index. The only guarantee of `Set`s is to have values determined to be unique by some criterion depending on the implementations. The `Collection` implementation which guarantees iteration order and access by index is `List`.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. Then please, show me what have I got to lose using a custom map ds made up of 2 arrays? (isolating the fact that they're unable to resize say, I use Lists or resizing doesn't matter)

Comment: Just one array of keys and one array of values?  When you get an arbitrary key that may or may not be in the map, how do you find it?  You really don't have any choice but to do an extremely expensive O(n) search through every element in the key array.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a HashMap as IndexMap where the index can be any Object (key) and it is mapped to another Object (value). An IndexMap in your sense would be just a List, a List maps an int index to an Object. But the indexes of a List cannot be Objects.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Why is that? Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: I've been trying come up with a better answer, but I think this explanation hits the nail on the head.

Comment: IndexMap is a name to oppose the HashMap that relates through hashing. This, in turn would relate through the common index of keys and values arrays/sets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at what your trying to ask. Why are Java HashMap not like [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)s or other special hashtable collections that do not require a hash (because the hash is pre-calculated).

Its because HashMap is a generic collection so that you can store any object. If you want a faster HashMap (ie fast hash) then certain assumptions need to be made about the data your storing in the Map (like `EnumMap`).

Comment: I'm dazzled of why do the keys have to be hashed in the first place, pre- or on the fly? This is the whole point: I expected a kind of Map that takes 2 arrays and correlates the elements by index. Arbitrary objects of some type in keys[] and Arbitrary objects of some other type in values[]

Answer (score 0):

I are in right direction but need to consider few more actions that you might want to perform on your data structure.

accessing in array costs o(1) which is same as in hash based data structure but searching could be very-very costly o(n) in array where as it is still same o(1) in hash based structure.

While deciding on which data structure is good for your application it depends what you are going to do on that data structure. For further reference please check this page which contains summary of different operation on different data structures:

http://simplenotions.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/java-standard-data-structures-big-o-notation/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. If I understand it right, a search like contains() would be more costly for an array O(n) than for a hash collection O(1)? Is this right?